# Where is ControlPanel or jcontrol for openjdk 1.8_222?

Tags: java

I installed openjdk 1.8_222 on ubuntu 18.04 but cannot find the ControlPanel or jcontrol on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

You have openjdk-8-jdk installed in Ubuntu 18.04. You can use exactly the same command line utilities with OpenJDK as with Oracle JDK, but ControlPanel and jcontrol do not exist in openjdk-8-jdk in Ubuntu 18.04.

The GUI in openjdk-8-jdk in Ubuntu 18.04 is named JConsole. The JConsole graphical user interface is a monitoring tool that uses the extensive instrumentation of the Java Virtual Machine (Java VM) to provide information about the performance and resource consumption of applications running on the Java platform. Once you have connected JConsole to an application, JConsole is composed of six tabs: Overview, Memory, Threads, Classes, VM Summary and MBeans.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ cd /usr/bin # path to jconsole
$ jconsole
```

The command `jconsole` will open the JConsole window.

[image]

Comment: In fact Iwant to access the security

Comment: In fact I want to access the security Panel but cannot find the ControlPanel or the equivalent

Answer (score 1):

in bash run

```
locate itweb-settings
```

and than run what it found, for example

```
/etc/alternatives/itweb-settings
```